# Migration from numeric ID to UUID

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I'm looking for any tips and suggestions when it comes to migrating from the numeric ID's to the UUID's in Ecto.

I'm having a project with a high amount of relations and I can't simply drop db and recreate it with UUID's, which seems like an easiest solution, because I have to keep the data.

My idea was:

1. Add `:uuid, :uuid` field to a table
2. Fill the `:uuid` column with a script and `Ecto.UUID.generate()`
3. Modify table to `(:some_table, primary_key: false)` and field to: `:uuid, :uuid, primary_key: true` and remove the `:id` field.
4. Rename the `:uuid` field to `:id`

Although it looked perfect in my mind I of course forgot about references. Is there any way I can handle references easily with a such migration from numeric ID's to UUID's? The only idea that comes to my mind is to create additional table, which will contain old ID and new UUID between 2nd and 3rd step, then remove old references and add new ones basing on the created table. I will appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: Please consider converting numeric ids into the stringified first and then you can gradually update ids for all models and references.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option to put DB into read-only state from outside for a while, it should not be too hard. I am not sure it’d work properly with new records arising during the update, though.

0. Drop all the foreign key constraints
1. Add `:uuid, :uuid` field to a table
2. Modify table to be `primary_key: false`
3. Put the trigger on `UPDATE` updating *all* the referring tables’ `fk` values to the inserted value
4. Fill the `:uuid` column with a DB procedure like `gen_uuid()`
5. Make `:uuid` to be a primary key (and remove `:id`)
6. Rename the `:uuid` field to `:id`

∞. Put all the foreign keys back in place.

The whole thing should be better done with pure SQL (save for [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) schema update.)